# What is the structure of JSON to be read by google-gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I was wondering, given the following JSON, how I can produce a `ResultSet` instance, which carry `Query` valued `ppb`?

```
package jsontest;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

/**
 *
 * @author yccheok
 */
public class Main {

    public static class ResultSet {
        public String Query;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        final String s = "{\"ResultSet\":{\"Query\":\"ppb\"}}";
        System.out.println(s);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        ResultSet resultSet = gson.fromJson(s, ResultSet.class);
        // {}
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(resultSet));
        // null?
        System.out.println(resultSet.Query);
    }
}
```

Currently, here is what I get :

```
{"ResultSet":{"Query":"ppb"}}
{}
null
```

Without modified the String, how can I get a correct Java object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try *first* to construct a new object, call `gson.toJson(object)`, and see the result.

I don't have gson, but jackson (another object-to-json mapper) prints this:

```
{"Query":"ppb"}
```

So, you don't include the class name. Actually, the [gson user guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) gives an example showing exactly this. Look at the `BagOfPrimitives`.

(And a final note - in Java, the accepted practice is that variables are lowercase - i.e. `query` rather than `Query`)

**Update** If you *really* can't change the json input, you can mirror the structure this way:

```
public static class Holder {
    public ResultSet ResultSet;
}

public static class ResultSet {
    public String Query;
}
```

(and then use `Holder h = gson.fromJson(s, Holder.class);`)

Comment: @Yan Cheng CHEOK That's not what I meant. Anyway, see my update

Comment: I have no control on the JSON string. It is returned from server.

Comment: OK. I can see I miss out the Holder class.